# Check if my SSL Certificate is SHA1 or SHA2

Tags: sha1, sha2

I have tried to find the answer to this but I couldn't find an answer...

How do I check if my SSL Certificate is using SHA1 or SHA2?

Reason I ask is because it might have to do with the certificate not loading on Mozilla Browers....

Any ideas? Can I check through cPanel?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can check by visiting the site in your browser and viewing the certificate that the browser received.  The details of how to do that can vary from browser to browser, but generally if you click or right-click on the lock icon, there should be an option to view the certificate details.

In the list of certificate fields, look for one called "Certificate Signature Algorithm".  (For StackOverflow's certificate, its value is "PKCS #1 SHA-1 With RSA Encryption".)

Comment: Yes exactly thanks - the answer is SHA-256 With RSA Encryption

Comment: i consider this the very simplest way! FYI: on Firefox x.x i used "Tools->Page Info" then the "Security" tab

Answer (score 50):

### Use the Linux Command Line

Use the command line, as described in this related question: [How do I check if my SSL Certificate is SHA1 or SHA2 on the commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473076/how-do-i-check-if-my-ssl-certificate-is-sha1-or-sha2-on-the-commandline).

#### Command

Here's the command. Replace `www.yoursite.com:443` to fit your needs. Default SSL port is 443:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.yoursite.com:443 < /dev/null 2>/dev/null \
    | openssl x509 -text -in /dev/stdin | grep "Signature Algorithm"
```

#### Results

This should return something like this for the sha1:

```
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
```

or this for the newer version:

```
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
```

#### References

The article [Why Google is Hurrying the Web to Kill SHA-1](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1) describes exactly what you would expect and has a pretty graphic, too.

Comment: In case you want to test an SMTP server with STARTTLS, use this: `openssl s_client -connect www.yoursite.com:25 -starttls smtp < /dev/null 2>/dev/null 
    | openssl x509 -text -in /dev/stdin | grep "Signature Algorithm"`

Answer (score 22):

**Update: The site below is no longer running** because, as they say on the site:

> As of January 1, 2016, no publicly trusted CA is allowed to issue a SHA-1 certificate. In addition, SHA-1 support was removed by most modern browsers and operating systems in early 2017. Any new certificate you get should automatically use a SHA-2 algorithm for its signature.
>
> Legacy clients will continue to accept SHA-1 certificates, and it is possible to have requested a certificate on December 31, 2015 that is valid for 39 months. So, it is possible to see SHA-1 certificates in the wild that expire in early 2019.

### Original answer:

You can also use https://shaaaaaaaaaaaaa.com/ - set up to make this particular task easy.  The site has a text box - you type in your site domain name, click the Go button and it then tells you whether the site is using SHA1 or SHA2.

[Background](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1)

Answer (score 3):

```
openssl s_client -connect api.cscglobal.com:443 < /dev/null 2>/dev/null  | openssl x509 -text -in /dev/stdin | grep "Signature Algorithm" | cut -d ":" -f2 | uniq | sed '/^$/d' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify this slightly to be used on a Windows System. Here's the one-liner version for a windows box.

```
openssl.exe s_client -connect yoursitename.com:443 > CertInfo.txt && openssl x509 -text -in CertInfo.txt | find "Signature Algorithm" && del CertInfo.txt /F
```

Tested on Server 2012 R2 using http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/gnuwin32/openssl/0.9.8h-1/openssl-0.9.8h-1-bin.zip