# How do I check if my SSL Certificate is SHA1 or SHA2 on the commandline

Tags: ssl, openssl, sha1, sha, sha256

How do I check if my SSL Certificate is using SHA1 or SHA2, from the commandline?

And yes, i this is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810999/how-do-i-check-if-my-ssl-certificate-is-sha1-or-sha2), but i need a cli-tool and i want to understand how it is done.

Answer (score 25):

after googling for quite some time i came up with the following snippet (unix):

```
openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -text -in /dev/stdin | grep "Signature Algorithm"
```

windows (thanx Nick Westgate, see below)

```
certutil -dump cacert.pem | find "Algorithm"
```

Comment: In my case on Windows with a .p12-certificate i used: certutil -dump crtname.p12 | find "Cert Hash"    (Also, my certificate had a password, so I had to type that in too after pressing enter.)

Answer (score 21):

I know the topic is old but I think

```
openssl x509 -in yourcert.crt -text -noout | grep "Signature Algorithm"
```

would be an easier solution.

Comment: This is exactly what the first answer eventually does. A certificate is usually installed on a web server and does not exist in a file, and rink.attendant.6's answer fetches the cerificate AND runs the verification check in a single line

Comment: @ShalomCarmel but this one is helpful to admins like myself who want to double-check a certificate we've inherited, and have shell access to the server :)

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify a platform, but in a Windows command prompt you can use:

```
certutil -dump cacert.pem | find "Algorithm"
```

Comment: included your answer, thanx

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell

```
PS C:\> certutil -dump cacert.pem | findstr "Algorithm"
```