# Facebook - How to test SHA-2 connections to Facebook before SHA-2 certificates are deployed?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently [Facebook said all API requests must be made using a using SHA-2 connection](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/06/02/SHA-2-Updates-Needed/) after Oct 1, 2015.

So from my understanding, this simply means that the SSL certificates that Facebook uses to encrypt traffic will now be signed using SHA-2, and I need to test my app to ensure it can connect to sites using SHA-2 certificates before their new certificates are deployed on Oct 1, 2015.

Is there a way I can test my app against Facebook's servers as if SHA-2 was already deployed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test any server-side software or apps that access Facebook services against the SHA256-only endpoint {www,graph,api}.sha256.facebook.com.

This endpoint will not be available for testing after December 31, 2015.

Example:
https://apps.sha256.facebook.com/candycrush/?fb_source=search&ref=br_tf

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a way to test it at Facebook itself, but I just made sure my HTTP Client could connect to a site using a SHA-2 signed certificate without error, which I could.

An easy way to do this is to use Github Pages, which has a SHA-2 signed certificate, and allows you to easily upload json or html files to test against, and can be accessed using `https://` SHA-2 urls as well. More info here:

https://pages.github.com/

Also you can test if your site's SSL certificate is already an SHA-2 cert using the tips [at this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810999/check-if-my-ssl-certificate-is-sha1-or-sha2), which suggests a few sites you can use to test your sites certificate online.

For example, here's the test result for `pages.github.com`

https://shaaaaaaaaaaaaa.com/check/pages.github.com

Comment: Facebook Partner Engineer here. You can use `{www,graph,api}.sha256.facebook.com` to test SHA-256 readiness between now and Dec 31st 2015. 

Since yours is the accepted answer, feel free to incorporate this into the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback... I couldn't find it before, but having an official answer is great. Much appreciated!

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how to test against facebook, but you can test if your client (or app) supports SHA-2 downloading this page: https://sha256rsa.comodoca.com

On mine windows XP service pack 2 the request didn't work, while in XP service pack 3 it works fine.