# Which SHA-2 function will Facebook use?

Tags: facebook, security, sha1, sha, sha2

I read that Facebook on the 1st Oct 2015 will move from SHA-1 to SHA-2 and we have to update our applications: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/06/02/SHA-2-Updates-Needed/

Do you know which function of SHA-2 will it use?

I read there are several (224, 256, 384 or 512) and one of these (SHA-224) doesn't work with the Windows XP SP3 which I use (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/01/23/sha-2-support-on-windows-xp.aspx)

Comment: Probably they'll support every hash function of the sha-2 family. There's no information about imposing particular one. I'd recommend to ask about security on http://security.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Check also: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/87154/what-is-the-relationship-between-sha-2-and-sha-256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to care that much because usage of the SHA-224 is quite limited.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30866583/facebook-how-to-test-sha-2-connections-to-facebook-before-sha-2-certificates-a) [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) has pointed out an important remark:

> That blog post is about SSL connections when your app is making API
>   requests. This is not about anything you do with data within your app,
>   it is about the transport layer.

According to the https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15151/sha-224-purpose

Answer by `Ilmari Karonen`:

> Honestly, in practice, there are very few if any reasons to use
>   SHA-224.
>
> [As fgrieu notes](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15151/sha-224-purpose/15155#15155), SHA-224 is simply SHA-256 with a different IV and
>   with 32 of the output bits thrown away. For most purposes, if you want
>   a hash with more than 128 but less than 256 bits, simply using SHA-256
>   and truncating the output yourself to the desired bit length is
>   simpler and just as efficient as using SHA-224. As you observe,
>   SHA-256 is also more likely to be available on different platforms
>   than SHA-224, making it the better choice for portability.
>
> Why would you ever want to use SHA-224, then?
>
> The obvious use case is if you need to implement an existing protocol
>   that specifies the use of SHA-224 hashes. While, for the reasons
>   described above, it's not a very common choice, I'm sure such
>   protocols do exist.
>
> Also, a minor advantage of SHA-224 over truncated SHA-256 is that, due
>   to the different IV, knowing the SHA-224 hash of a given message does
>   not reveal anything useful about its SHA-256 hash, or vice versa. This
>   is really more of an "idiot-proofing" feature; since the two hashes
>   have different names, careless users might assume that their outputs
>   have nothing in common, so NIST changed the IV to ensure that this is
>   indeed the case.
>
> However, this isn't really something you should generally rely on. If
>   you really need to compute multiple unrelated hashes of the same input
>   string, what you probably want instead is a keyed PRF like HMAC, which
>   can be instantiated using any common hash function (such as SHA-256).

As you've mentioned, Windows XP with SP3 doesn't support SHA-224 but it supports [SHA-256](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1499561-sha-256-compatibility):
[image]

Check also: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/what-are-the-realistic-and-most-secure-crypto-for-symmetric-asymmetric-hash

Especially: https://stackoverflow.com/a/817121/3964066

And: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/1755

Part of the Thomas Pornin's answer:

> ECDSA over a 256-bit curve already achieves an "unbreakable" level of
>   security (i.e. roughly the same level than AES with a 128-bit key, or
>   SHA-256 against collisions). Note that there are elliptic curves on
>   prime fields, and curves on binary fields; which kind is most
>   efficient depends on the involved hardware (for curves of similar
>   size, a PC will prefer the curves on a prime field, but dedicated
>   hardware will be easier to build with binary fields; the CLMUL
>   instructions on the newer Intel and AMD processors may change that).
>
> SHA-512 uses 64-bit operations. This is fast on a PC, not so fast on a
>   smartcard. SHA-256 is often a better deal on small hardware (including
>   32-bit architectures such as home routers or smartphones)

Comment: thank you Belford. Also facebook replied me "but you should be using SHA256."