# SHA2 issue with SSL certificates in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

My site on Google Chrome gets a warning about its SSL certificate. At first Chrome says:

> The identity of this website has been verified by RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3  but does not have public audit records.

But then I get a warning like that:

> This site uses a weak security configuration (SHA-1 signatures), so your connection may not be private.

When i check my certificate by openssl from commandline based on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26685515/317648 I get an answer like that:

> Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption

I am confused now, why Chrome says it can be SHA1. What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the certificate itself is using SHA-256, the certificates upward in the chain are likely using SHA1. You will likely need to upgrade your certificate chain files to use a more up to date version of the certificates, so in order to do this you should be able to download a new intermediate certificate from your issuer.

You can find more information on this particular issue here: [Why Chrome Thinks your SHA-2 Certificate Chain is "Affirmatively Insecure"](https://sslmate.com/blog/post/chrome_cached_sha1_chains)

More information on why Google are sunsetting SHA1 is available here: [Why Google is Hurrying the Web to Kill SHA-1](https://konklone.com/post/why-google-is-hurrying-the-web-to-kill-sha-1).